How to replicate Vergil's Judgement cut end Effect sword path in Blender?
I'm wondering how to say the material like Vergil's judgment cut end in Devil May Cry 5. The effect of the sword strokes. I'll link a video to help demonstrate the effect I'm looking to replicate: https://youtu.be/GEZON93hV-s?t=28. Help me pls. 

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
